# Google auto-recognizing menus?

Tags: html, seo

I wondered what would be the markup to achieve the following on google, somehow they recognize the menu items and show it as part of the search result but I couldn't find an easy way to do it.

attached screenshot:
[image]

Comment: All of a sudden this 8 months old question was closed as off topic after 3 comments and a selected answer? ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you are asking how to cause "sitelinks" to appear for your website. Unfortunately as far as SEO is concerned, there isn't any special markup you can use to make these appear. They will be shown if Google's algorithm determines it is appropriate to show them, otherwise, they won't be.

For more information, see the following help article from the Google webmaster tools:
http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=47334&topic=8523

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything special about the markup.  Google needs to be able to crawl the site and be able to determine the site's structure based on how pages link to each other.  In addition, you can tell Google how the site is structured by submitting a [sitemap](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156184) to them.  This is a simple step you can do to encourage Google to build this structure in their search results.  Be patient for the results to occur, however, as it can take a while.

Answer (score 0):

A good site navigation tree (logical) and breadcrumbs on the internal page, may help google to check right your "menu". [HTML5](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_nav.asp) too maybe a good idea to say to search engine "Hi. I'm the nav".